# Converting decimal number to 16 bit temperature binary

Tags: binary, decimal, sensors, data-conversion, temperature

I have a question about conversion.
In a document about DS18B20 temperature sensor i need to convert 18.25C to binary.
Can someone explain how to do it.
[image: This is the examples i have]

I tried looking for answers on the internet but i can't find anything similar.

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the binary value is the decimal temperature in increments of 0.0635 degrees (`0.5 = 0.0625*8 = 0008h`, `10.125 = 0.0625*162 = 00A2h`)

so the conversion for `18.25` would be

```
18.25/0.0625 = 292 = 0124h = 0000 0001 0010 0010
```

Or, since `1/0.0625 = 16`, you could convert it by multiplying by 16:

```
18.25 * 16 = 292 = 0124h = 0000 0001 0010 0010
```

Comment: Yeah, multiply float value by 16 then convert to ushort, right?

Comment: Yes that's another way to look at it. Added.